# adding an id to divs with no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey i am trying to add an id to all divs that don't have a id.

i am new to this and did some research but could not find what i needed and not even sure this can be done?

i did tried some things but could only add an id to every div even if it's already got one but i only want to give it an id if it don't have one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>
```

i would really appreciate it if some one can point me in the right direction

Comment: What `id` do you want to add? Just any random one?

Comment: yes i would like to add a random id to every div with no id

Comment: What's the point of adding random ids to every div? It doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below logic where you can filter all divs and find if id present or not and if not present then add one.

```js
$(function(){
  var idCount=0;
  $("div").filter(function(){
     return !$(this).attr('id');
  }).attr('id', "dynamicId" + idCount++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice this also works and just what i'm looking for thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `div`s which have no ids with the selector `div:not([id])`, then iterate over them with `querySelectorAll`. Note that duplicate IDs in the same document is **invalid HTML** - you should change your lower `advertCenterPanel` to `advertCenterPanel2` for it to be valid (or use a class instead, it's not clear what purpose the IDs serve).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])')
  .forEach((div) => {
    div.id = 'random' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
  });
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin: 30px -6px 0px; height: 250px;">
  <div id="advertCenterPanel2" class="text-center">
    Somthing here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is just what i needed! and works just like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used jquery, you can try this:

```
$("elementSelector").uniqueId();
```

Reference: https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/

Generate and apply a unique id for the set of matched elements.

Comment: Unfortunately this requiewa jQueryUI in addition to plain ol jQuery. See: http://jsfiddle.net/0a4z5dp1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each div and check if alredy has an id like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id')) {
            $(this).addClass('red');
            $(this).attr('id','mynewid');
            //do anything
        }
    })
});
```

Now in css you can add your stuff when element gets mynewid like

```
#mynewid {
    background: yellow;
}
```